# Django Rest Framework Manipulating Serialize.pop

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying a view function that does the necessary operation depending on the data coming from the body. There is a registration model serializer that takes an additional variable group and if the group is student, the institute ID will have "ST22" at the beginning. I couldn't find a way to pop 'group' from serializer before sending it to the database. The data is saved but since it sends group as well and It does not have a field, it throws an error.

post function:

```
    def post(self, request, format='json'):
    serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        if (serializer.validated_data["group"].lower() == "student"):
            serializer.validated_data["institute_id"]= "ST22" + serializer.validated_data["institute_id"]      
        user = serializer.save()
        if user:
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status= status.HTTP_418_IM_A_TEAPOT)
```

serializer class:

```
class StudentRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
group = serializers.CharField()
class Meta:
    model= CustomUser
    fields= ("id", "username", "password", "institute_id", "group")
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {
            'write_only': True
            }
        }

def create(self, validated_data):
    password = validated_data.pop('password')
    password = validated_data.pop('group')
    user = CustomUser(**validated_data)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

error:
CustomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'

Comment: Can you add the error as well?

Comment: I have added it to my post. Sorry i forgot.

Answer (score 0):

```
group: str
```

instead of

```
group = serializers.CharField()
```

you can access to group using request.data and you won't need to manipulate serializer. You you can send query inside body as follows:

```
{
"username": "",
"password": "",
"institute_id": "",
"group": ""
}
```